# React Native UseEffect stuck in loop calling function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to update a state based on a user's touch event, and then I use useEffect to try to call a function where it updates another state so that it can be passed to the next screen by using navigation.

The problem is I am getting stuck in a loop and I have no idea why. It should only be called when the `selectedSet` is updated.

```
  const [pokemonCards, setPokemonCards] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSet, setSelectedSet] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPokemonCards = () => {
      PokemonTCG.findCardsByQueries({ q: 'set.id:' + selectedSet, pageSize: 10 }).then(
        (cards) => {
          console.log("cards: ", cards)
          setPokemonCards(cards);
        }
      )
    }
    getPokemonCards();
  }, [selectedSet]);
```

...

```
  <TouchableHighlight key={pokemonSet.id} onPress = {() => {
    setSelectedSet(pokemonSet.id);
    navigation.navigate("SetDetails", { setID: pokemonSet.id, pokemonSetDetails: pokemonSet, pokemonCards: pokemonCards });
  }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'useEffect' refetches the pokemon cards, which creates new pokemontSet objects, which rerenders the object with the "new" selected pokemonSet.id. And because the selectedId is changed the effect is triggered.

Comment: What is the correct way to use useEffect in this example?